# Upgrading to Angular 10 breaks ExcelJs

Tags: angular, exceljs

I have just upgraded my application from the last version of 9 to angular 10 using ng update.
I know there are significant changes, and in the most part it has upgraded well, however I am currently getting an error from exceljs:

```
"export 'Workbook' (imported as 'Excel') was not found in 'exceljs/dist/exceljs'
```

Prior to the upgrade, it was using exceljs version 2.0.1. Now it is using exceljs 4.0.1. (It is one version prior to the latest version, because there is an error preventing compiling in the latest version due to an option argument being marked as required. That shouldn't matter.)

The import statement is as follows:

```
import * as Excel from "exceljs/dist/exceljs";
```

The code itself is pretty typical for exceljs. I have a service that provides data: HttpResponse and I load it into the workbook so that I can extract some of the columns.

```
this.myService.getMySpreadsheet().subscribe((data: HttpResponse<Blob>) => {
      new Response(data.body).arrayBuffer().then(arrayBuffer => {
        const wb: Excel.Workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
        wb.xlsx.load(arrayBuffer).then(() => {

          const ws1 = wb.getWorksheet("My Worksheet");
```

But it can't even get to that code now, because the angular compilation is broken.

Any idea how I can fix that problem? Is there some sort of backward compatibility flag that I need to add?

Comment: Did you try to re-run npm install?

Comment: yep, one of the first things I did.

Comment: I just upgraded node to 12.18.2. It made no difference.

Comment: I ended up having to roll back. It might require a revisit from the ExcelJS team.I hope someone gets this working soon, or there is an alternative that works.

Comment: Can you share the error it's giving while compiling?

Comment: @tone Have you look into this `https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/810`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got `exceljs` working with `agnular 10` with below `tsconfig.app.json` settings, notice the `paths` and `types` properties under `compilerOptions` -

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "paths": {
     "exceljs": [
       "node_modules/exceljs/dist/exceljs.min"
     ]
   },
    "types": ["node"],
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

and then you can import `Workbook` and create worksheet like below -

```
import { Workbook } from 'exceljs';
....
let workbook = new Workbook();
let worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Sample sheet');
```

Please checkout the working [sample app here](https://github.com/akashsolanki/exceljs-angular10)